# Copy and Paste values (as Text) every hour from a Static Table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to scripts as you can see, I need a script where in I can get a data on a table (Sheet 1!A1:E7 - which updates every hour as well) and copy it (as TEXT) to a new sheet (Sheet 2). I need Sheet 2 to generate new rows/columns with the every hour (24 hrs) for 7 days. I searched the whole net to find this, but to no avail though.

Hoping to find answers to this.

Answer (score 0):

Surpised the internet didn't throw up anything to learn how to script, but will share the route I took with you.

[Codeacademy. Great for learning the basic priciples of Javascript](http://www.codecademy.com/)

Once you've done there, next stop should be here.

[This is googles reference site for scripting. But also has a few have a go tutorials that give insight into Google Application scripts and how they work.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)

That should give you a great starting point to build your own scripts.
I'd also keep this link to hand, for great rerefences, W3Schools

[Has javascript references and tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

You'll be on your way in no time at all, and once you hit brick walls, or code isn't behaving properly. There is good old HERE, StackOverflow to visit.

I don't understand what you mean in your question "Generate new columns"
because if the source table is always A1:E7 then you don't need extra columns on sheet 2. Only extra rows as new data is imported.

This is a quick solution to your question.

```
function tableCopy() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var values = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:E7").getValues();

  var valuesLength = values.length;
  if (!valuesLength) return; 





  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  var requiredRows = lastRow + valuesLength - targetSheet.getMaxRows();
  if (requiredRows > 0) targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, requiredRows);
    targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, valuesLength, values[0].length).setValues(values);



}
```

to get it working as a timer, you will have to add a time driven trigger to the function. To trigger it at the times you require.

I hope this helps